# Background Stream Windows 8?

Tags: javascript, audio, background, microsoft-metro, runtime

I've been trying to get background audio working for quite a bit this evening! The HTML5 attribute for the audio tag, 'msAudioCategory', it appears, is not a valid one. It's quite odd, I can't find help for this issue anywhere.

Please excuse me in advanced if I don't understand your answer.
My default.js (Started at a random point to make it shorter):

```
 app.onactivated = function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
            if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {

            } else {
                // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
                // Restore application state here.
            }
            args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
        }
    };

    app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
        // TODO: This application is about to be suspended. Save any state
        // that needs to persist across suspensions here. You might use the
        // WinJS.Application.sessionState object, which is automatically
        // saved and restored across suspension. If you need to complete an
        // asynchronous operation before your application is suspended, call
        // args.setPromise().
        // Declare a variable that you will use as an instance of an object
        var mediaControls;

        // Assign the button object to mediaControls
        mediaControls = Windows.Media.MediaControl;

        // Add an event listener for the Play, Pause Play/Pause toggle button
        mediaControls.addEventListener("playpausetogglepressed", playpausetoggle, false);
        mediaControls.addEventListener("playpressed", playbutton, false);
        mediaControls.addEventListener("pausepressed", pausebutton, false);
        mediaControls.addEventListener("stoppressed", stop, false);

        // The event handler for the play/pause button
        function playpausetoggle() {
            if (mediaControls.isPlaying === true) {
                document.getElementById("playback").pause();
            } else {
                document.getElementById("playback").play();
            }
        }

        // The event handler for the pause button
        function pausebutton() {
            document.getElementById("playback").pause();
        }

        // The event handler for the play button
        function playbutton() {
            document.getElementById("playback").play();
        }
        // The event handler for the stop button
        function stop() {
            document.getElementById("playback").pause();
            document.getElementById("playback").currentTime = 0;
        }
    };

    app.start();

}
()


);
```

Element Tag:

```
 <audio id="audtag" autoplay="autoplay" msAudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" src="http://-Hidden-:8000/;">

 </audio>
```

I'm pretty sure I've configured everything correctly. I made sure I had the background function or something set up. However, it still says the audio element attribute 'msAudioCategory' is not valid HTML5. Where do I put the JavaScript in default.js to define that attribute? After app.start()? The documentation in the file is confusing to me.

The first time making an app is always supposed to be easy!

Answer (score 0):

did you set the correct declarations in app manifest ?
you need to add Background Tasks and set task types as Audio and Control Channel.

I just got this working on C# sample yesterday